# supporting paypal in-country account currencies for online transactions

Tags: paypal

In the list of paypal currencies supported, given here https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_currency_codes , two currencies (MYR, BRL) are marked with a the following note.

**NOTE:This currency is supported as a payment currency and a currency balance for in-country PayPal accounts only.**

I am running an app where I allow Customer A to pay to Customer B through paypal and record the transaction details in my app through IPN.

**What should I do to support these two currencies along with other paypal currencies?**

**How do I know If an account has the in-country account so I can enable payments in that currency as well?**

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could request access to the AddressVerify API to get the COUNTRYCODE of the buyer's registered postal address in his/her PayPal account. You'll need to contact their Customer Support to get this enabled on your account.

You can find a list of supported currencies per product at https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/240/kw/currency/sno/1
It looks like neither MYR or BRL are supported though..

Answer (score 0):

I think what u need is PayPal Adaptive Payments. And Paypal Adaptive Payments supports currency convert function.
ref: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/